# Div width making "special" moves in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have made a nav section with a couple of dropdown buttons. 
I would like to set the width of the div's by the text lenght.
I tought I did a pretty good job, according to the result in Firefox. (the exact result I would like)

However, checking the site in Chrome, the whole nav section is completely reacting different. 
The text is breaking up, div width isn't right anymore.
But the strangest thing is that when I hover on the buttons, the div width's start to react and changing to the right settings.

Is this a Chrome thing, or do I need to make my code on different way?

I'm using `normalize.css` in my parent css file.

This is the website: http://callensdecor.be/preview/

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
       <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Onze diensten</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="schilderwerken.html">Schilderwerken</a></li>
            <li><a href="totaalwerken.html">Totaalwerken</a></li>
            <li><a href="andere.html">Andere werken</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav{
    float:right;    
    padding-top:68px;
}

nav ul{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    width:100%;
}

nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}


nav li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:2%;
}

nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    min-width:75px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    color:#555555;
    padding:7px 13% 10px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav li a:hover, .selected{
    background-color:#838383;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 0px; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 35px;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:0%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    color:#555555;
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    margin-top:3px;
    width:auto;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #838383;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Google Chrome this works:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47xa2/1/) <-- See the jsfiddle

It look's like the `padding` in the `nav ul li a{` is messing it up for you.

Comment: the padding was indeed the troublemaker. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said it's the 13% padding here:

```
nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    min-width:75px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    color:#555555;
    padding:7px 13% 10px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

that is screwing with you change it to a px value and you should be good to go :D